# AHK F11 = ctrl+shift+1, sleep 10ms, ctrl+shift+7

Tags: autohotkey

i want auto hot key to do this:

F11  = ctrl+shift+1
sleep 10ms
ctrl+shift+7

I have:

F11::Send{{^}{+}{1}{Sleep 10}{^}+{7}}
Return

Thanks for any help

Comment: Context ? which OS / Language ?

Comment: Context: I am working with alignment tools in software(atvise builder)
OS is windows server 2016, but i think win10 works the same.
Language is AHK, (auto hot key) if i understand the question correctly.

Comment: See [Sending Keystrokes](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s3). I'd read the whole Tutorial first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
F11::
Send, ^+1
Sleep 10
Send, ^+7
Return
```

Comment: You would use curly braces to enclose key *names*, the shortcuts names such as “#” and “+” are simply short cuts. Sleep needs to be on its own line I think. Multi line scripts following a hotkey start after the hotkey.